# Pytorch LSTM not training

Tags: python, lstm, pytorch, sequence-to-sequence

So I am currently trying to implement an LSTM on Pytorch, but for some reason the loss is not decreasing. Here is my network:

```
class MyNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size=3, seq_len=107, pred_len=68, hidden_size=50, num_layers=1, dropout=0.2):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.pred_len = pred_len
        
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(
            input_size=input_size, 
            hidden_size=hidden_size, 
            num_layers=num_layers, 
            dropout=dropout, 
            bidirectional=True,
            batch_first=True
        )
        
        self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size*2, 5)
    
    def forward(self, X):
        lstm_output, (hidden_state, cell_state) = self.rnn(X)
        
        labels = self.linear(lstm_output[:, :self.pred_len, :])
        
        return lstm_output, labels
```

And my training loop

```
LEARNING_RATE = 1e-2


net = MyNN(num_layers=1, dropout=0)

compute_loss = nn.MSELoss()

optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)


all_loss = []
for data in tqdm(list(train_loader)):
    X, y = data
    
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    lstm_output, output = net(X.float())
    
    # Computing the loss
    loss = compute_loss(y, output)
    all_loss.append(loss)
    loss.backward()
    
    optimizer.step()
    
# Plot
plt.plot(all_loss, marker=".")
plt.xlabel("Epoch")
plt.xlabel("Loss")
plt.show()
```

And this is what I got
[image]

I have been trying to look for what the hell I am doing wrong but I have no idea. Also, before I used a keras LSTM and it worked well on the dataset.

Any help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You look at loss at every batch. You should average your loss over all batches. When you look at different batches your loss may increase simply because one batch is harder to predict than the other one. That's why it's not really interpretable. So start with that. If the problem persists it's probably exploding gradients. In that case lower your learning rate to `1e-3` or `1e-4` or even less if it continues.

Comment: Hmm had already tried lowering the LR.  What I didn't do was trying to clip the gradients, because I did not think this could be exploding gradients. I will try it and see if it solves it. Thanks!

Comment: If lower LR didn't help gradient clipping shouldn't work either because they both do nothing more than scale/clip gradients. Take a look at my edit though.

Comment: Omg that makes total sense... I knew I was making some idiot  mistake. I spent an afternoon yesterday thinking I was calling the loss function in a wrong way or something like that. I will check it later when I have the chance and then accept the answer. Thank you!